# How to test that two covariates have the same impact on dependent variable?

Tags: multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, scales

Given the model

$y =\beta_0 + \beta_1 x_1 + \beta_2 x_2 + u $

where $x_1$ and $x_2$ have completely different scales and units, is it possible to test whether their impact on $y$ is the same? i.e. is there a specific test for this?

I don't think testing  $H_0:\beta_1 = \beta_2$ is the right thing to do because of the different interpretations of the estimates.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,

Jona.

Comment: Can you convert them to standard deviations before running the regression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to standardize the covariates first (subtract mean and divide by standard deviation).  This puts the 2 covariates on the same scale and their coefficients can be compared directly.

This works best if both covariates are reasonably symmetric without outliers/heavy tails.  Strong skewness or outliers in one of the covariates can mess with the estimated standard deviation and make the comparison less meaningful.